# Updating MySQL database character set using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is there a way to update a MySQL database character set using Laravel, perhaps the DB facade? I know I can just run the statement in something like MySQL Workbench, but I wanted to create a job that would run several updates to tables following the database update.

I wanted to run:

`DB::statement("ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci");`

But I'm getting an error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().`

Is there a way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do or should I just run the statement separately from the job?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`DB::connection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`

I generally reset this after I'm running my statements:

`DB::connection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

Comment: This does the trick indeed, although an explanation of why is that would be welcome :)